# Power series and computation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $F\colon \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the functions defined by:

$$ F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}$$

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$

Show that 
$$ F(z) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^z-1}{z}  & \text{for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$} \\
1 & \text{if $z=0$}
\end{cases}$$

and show that $xf'(x) + f(x) = e^x$

---

It is trivial that for $F(z) = 0\ \text{if $z=0$}$
However, I am not sure how to show that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ $F(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$.

In order to show that $xf'(x) + f(x) = e^x$ I know that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $xf'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot \frac{x^{n-1}\cdot x}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!}$

$x'f(x) + f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot \frac{x^{n}}{(n+1)!}$

Where do I go from here to get $e^x$?

Comment: It should be $F(0)=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!}=\frac{1}{z}(\color{blue}{e^z-1})$$
**edit:** For the second part,

> $$xf'(x) + f(x)=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{(n+1)!}=e^x$$ by cancelling $(n+1)$ from the fraction.

Comment: I am a bit uncertain about the index shift in the last part, is it always allowed to do as it is just an index? Would I have to do the same when I have to show that $x'f(x) + f(x) = e^x$ ?

Comment: Of course you're allowed, since that's just a change of variable, but I stick to the use on $n$.

Comment: @MartinWinther Please see the edit.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^n}{(n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$ 
Just a question, if it simply was $f'(x) + f(x)$ then you would have to change the index to $n=1$ for $f'(x)$ in order to add the two series together right? so $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^n}{(n+1)!}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: But why I can add two series together? You can try to write that out to see: for each $n$, they have the same denominator. This is why I can add them as a new series.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
zF(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\mathrm{e}^z-1.
$$
Then
$$
\mathrm{e}^z=(\mathrm{e}^z-1)'=\big(zF(z)\big)'=F(z)+zF'(z)
$$